# Delete files from Xcode 4 project with AppleScript

Tags: xcode, applescript

I have the script like this

```
tell application "Xcode"
    tell project 1
        delete file reference 1 of group 1
    end tell
end tell
```

But in result I have `error "Xcode got an error: AppleEvent handler failed." number -10000`

How can I delete files from Xcode project with AppleScript?